# kube-up.sh is deprecated. What is the alternative

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to spin up a Kube cluster on AWS.

The documentation (http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/) specifically mentions that kube-up.sh is deprecated.

What is the correct way to configure the cluster? What is the alternative to kube-up.sh?

Answer (score 2):

The information is in the article you linked to.

You can either use [Kube Ops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) or coreos's [kube-aws](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-aws.html)